# Permission issue while mysql installation using Homebrew on OSX

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew

My mysql setup got corrupted which I installed using dmg file, I tried link [this link](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/uninstall-mysql-mac-os-x)
to clear all traces of mysql and re-installed using dmg again, but I was facing same issue, so I decided to do it with homebrew using [installation via homebrew link](https://coderwall.com/p/os6woq/uninstall-all-those-broken-versions-of-mysql-and-re-install-it-with-brew-on-mac-mavericks)

But that also didn't work and giving me below error while running the command `brew install mysql`

```
Error: Permission denied - /tmp/github_api_headers20161012-13067-iv1vz
```

I tried changing owner also but that also didn't work for me:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /tmp/
```

Someone has faced any such issue??

I am using OSX Yosemite 10.10.3